# Next Without For / For Without Next Error

Tags: vba, for-loop, syntax-error

I have the following code...that I've discussed before on here. It's been evolving though, so it's a little different now, I think.

```
Option Explicit
Public i As Integer
Public oOccurrence As ComponentOccurrence

Public Sub ReplaceComponent()
    Dim NameStr As String
    Dim NewNamePath As String

    Dim NameStr2 As String
    Dim OldNamePath As String

    NameStr = Renamer.New_Name.Text               'Concatenates the full new file path
    NewNamePath = Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"

    NameStr2 = Renamer.Old_Name_Display.Text      'Concatenates the old file NAME
    OldNamePath = NameStr2 & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"


    'Creates a ton of errors that have been giving me a headache
    Dim oOcc As ComponentOccurrence

    For Each oOcc In ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences
        If oOcc.ReferencedDocumentDescriptor.FullDocumentName = OldNamePath Then
            Set oOccurrence = oOcc
        End If
        Do While i < 99
            oOcc.Replace NewNamePath, True

            If i = 99 Then
                DeletetheDirectory
                                              'Will close the file
                Resolve_and_Open.Show vbModal                 'Reopens form 3 to select the next assembly
            Else:     
                For i = 1 To 99 Step 1
                Next

            End If
        Loop

End Sub
```

So right now I get a "For Without Next" error on the "End Sub" line. If I add in a next, anywhere, I get a "Next Without For" error. I imagine it has something to do with my "If...then" statements, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any ideas?

Edit 1:

Here is the DeletetheDirectory module. I don't have a problem with it. I use it throughout my forms as well:

```
Option Explicit

' Delete this directory and all the files it contains.
  Sub DeletetheDirectory()

  Dim FSO
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  FSO.deletefolder "C:\\InventorTempFolder"

  On Error Resume Next

  End Sub
```

And Resolve_and_Open is a form, which I also don't have any problems with:

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()

Unload Me                                                                        'Triggers cancel button
DeletetheDirectory

End Sub

Private Sub Open_Button_Click()

ThisApplication.SilentOperation = True                'Suppresses the resolve links dialog

Dim myPath As String
myPath = FileName.Text                                              'Gets the string, FileName, from module 1
Dim Shell As Object
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.Open (myPath)                                                      'Opens selected file

Resolve_and_Open.Hide                                               'Hides module
ReplaceComponent

'ReplaceComponent will go here once it works

End Sub

Private Sub OpenAssemblies_Click()

SelectFileOpenDialog                                                    'Calls to OpenFileDialog Module

End Sub
```

Comment: The outer For doesn't have a Next so you should just need to put it before the End Sub.

What's the : after the Else statement for?  Is that just a typo?

Comment: It automatically changes it to that actually. Not sure why. When I put it right before end sub I get an invalid next control variable reference error

Comment: You should remove the colon at the end of the Else. VBA will think that this is a label.

Comment: It automatically adds the colon when I delete it.

Comment: A colon means breakline in vba. It's used for mutliple code segments at once. `Dim examp1, examp2 as String : examp1 = "1" : examp2 = "2"`

Comment: Why does it automatically add it in then...? :/ I'm still new to this but I'm trying really hard to learn

Comment: It's just conditional code formatting specific to your hosting application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Next is missing as stated above.
2. Resolve_and_Open  is this a local command? is not declared as an object.
3. DeletetheDirectory is this a local command? or was this ever declared as a function?
4. You need proper error handling to collect where the code is breaking.
5. You are reactivating your variable (i) in your nested for loop under the Do While Loop which also utilizing (i).

Try this VBS and post your error responses.

```
    Option Explicit
    Public i As Integer
    Public oOccurrence As Object

    Public Sub ReplaceComponent()

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim NameStr As String
    Dim NewNamePath As String

    Dim NameStr2 As String
    Dim OldNamePath As String

    NameStr = Renamer.New_Name.Text               'Concatenates the full new file path
    NewNamePath = Renamer.Path_Text.Text & "\" + NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"
    if err.number<>0 then msgbox "Error Found After NewNamePath:" & err.description
    err.clear

    NameStr2 = Renamer.Old_Name_Display.Text      'Concatenates the old file NAME
    OldNamePath = NameStr2 & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3) & ".ipt"
    if err.number<>0 then msgbox "Error Found After OldNamePath:" & err.description
    err.clear

    'Creates a ton of errors that have been giving me a headache
    Dim oOcc As Object
    if err.number<>0 then msgbox "Error Found After oOcc:" & err.description
    err.clear

    Dim Occs As Object : Set Occs = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition.Occurrences
    if isArray(Occs) then
    For k=0 to Ubound(Occs)
        msgbox "Activated object, verifying object properties: " & oOcc.Name
        if err.number<>0 then msgbox "Could not activate object."
        err.clear
        If oOcc.ReferencedDocumentDescriptor.FullDocumentName = OldNamePath Then
            Set oOccurrence = oOcc
        End If
        if err.number<>0 then msgbox "Error Found After oOccurrence declaration:" & err.description
        err.clear 

        Do While i < 99
            oOcc.Replace NewNamePath, True
            if err.number<>0 then msgbox "Error Found After oOcc.Replace:" & err.description
            err.clear

            If i = 99 Then
                DeletetheDirectory
                if err.number<>0 then msgbox "Error Found After DeleteTheDirectory:" & err.description
                err.clear
                                              'Will close the file
                Resolve_and_Open.Show vbModal                 'Reopens form 3 to select the next assembly
                if err.number<>0 then msgbox "Error Found After Resolve_and_Open:" & err.description
                err.clear
            Else:     
                For j = 1 To 99 Step 1
                Next

            End If
        Loop
     Next oOcc
     Else
             Msgbox "Occurrences does not contain an Array" 
     End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Lost at step 3, lost at step 4, could not activate object, and Error found after oOccurrence declaration:Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Is it not finding the application at all then or is it not finding the component...?

Comment: Your application cannot find the `ThisApplication.ActiveDocument.ComponentDefinition` object, that is why it cannot iterate through the occurrences.

Comment: Well that is unfortunate. I will work on that then. Thank you so much for all of your help, Rich :)

Comment: No problem, I hope this has given you some guidance on how to properly troubleshoot your code as well. :) Best of luck to you.

Comment: It definitely has. I've read a lot about making sure you have error-handling built in but I had no idea how to go about doing that. I've just been adjusting my code until I stop getting errors. I'm sure my co-workers will find things I missed though too haha.

Comment: Well I'm glad we got it figured out. Don't forget to mark an answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each oOcc ...
```

needs a corresponding

```
Next oOcc
```

Comment: This gets me a run-time error 91, object variable not set :( I'd thought of that too

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
For Each oOcc ...
    ...
Next oOcc
```

also what is the point of this loop:

```
Else:     
            For i = 1 To 99 Step 1
            Next
```

?

Comment: I'd thought of that. And so did someone else. This is what I responded below: "This gets me a run-time error 91, object variable not set :( I'd thought of that too: